# Compare words in one file

Tags: objective-c

I have started learning programming in ObjC from
*"Objective-C Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide"*

In a task to exercise the learned stuff I've had to write a program what compares the the names in the file /usr/share/dict/words if there are same proper names (capitalized) and normal words (uncapitalized).

This is my program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    // Zähler für die Anzahl der Suchergebnisse
    int counter = 0;

    // Hier die Suchbegriffe eingeben
    NSString *search1 = @"Da";
    NSString *search2 = @"d";

    // Prüfung ob search1 und search2 identisch sind, wenn nicht eine Warnmeldung ausgeben.
    if ([search1 caseInsensitiveCompare:search2] != NSOrderedSame) {

        NSLog(@"Wenn du unterschiedliche Wörter suchst, wird die Suche lange dauern und zu keinem Ergebnis führen.");
        NSLog(@"Suche ist gestartet...");
        sleep(2);

    }   else {NSLog(@"Suche wird gestartet...");
        sleep(2);

    // Liest Datei als großen String ein (mögliche Fehler werden ausgeblendet
    NSString *namestring = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/usr/share/dict/words"
                                                    encoding:NSUncachedRead
                                                        error:NULL];

    // Zerlegt Datei in ein Array mit Strings
    NSArray *names = [namestring componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    // Suchalgorithmus
    // Geht das Array in der 1. Dimension einen String nach dem anderen durch
    for (NSString *n in names) {

        // Sucht nach dem String search1
        NSRange r = [n rangeOfString:search1 options:NSAnchoredSearch];

        // Wurde für search1 etwas gefunden?
        if (r.location != NSNotFound) {

            // Geht das Array in der 2. Dimension einen String nach dem anderen durch
            for (NSString *m in names) {

                // Sucht nach dem String search2
                NSRange q = [m rangeOfString:search2 options:NSAnchoredSearch];

                // Wurde für search2 etwas gefunden?
                if (q.location != NSNotFound) {
                    if ([n caseInsensitiveCompare:m] == NSOrderedSame) {
                        NSLog(@"%@ is equal to %@", n, m);

                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Es wurden %i Suchergebnisse gefunden", counter);
    }
    NSLog(@"Es wurden %i Suchergebnisse gefunden", counter);
}
return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm German.

Is there a way to do the same but more elegantly?

It's not necessary to tell me the complete code. It's better to give me some tips on which way would be better.

Answer (score 5):

The first most glaring problem I see is `sleep(2)`.  We really don't want to be doing this, particularly with Objective-C programs.  The main reason I add emphasis on Objective-C is because virtually every program written in Objective-C is either an OSX or iOS app with a GUI.  And in these cases, the main thread is the thread that handles the GUI.  You'll also be writing the bulk of your code on the main thread--certainly until you start figuring out multithreading.  Everything defaults on the main thread.

And a call to `sleep(someNum)` on the main thread means that the user only has one way of interacting with our program for `someNum` amount of time--by closing it out.

There are other ways to delay actions in our code without putting the entire thread to sleep.  In the case of this simple code, there's no interaction anyways, but in the future, you will run into this problem.

For the most simple example of how to point you in the right direction, Objective-C offers `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` (though this requires the use of objects & methods).

But there's also a non-OOP way of executing code after delays in Objective-C (it's a lot messier than `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, and I had to look up the exact syntax...).  It makes use of code blocks.

A code block is similar to a C-style function, but we have a variable that is a pointer to it (yes, I know C and other languages have "function pointers"--we call them blocks in Objective-C).  Anyway, the syntax for executing code in a block after a delay looks like this:

```
int delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // any code you want executed after delay
    // in this case, delay is 2 seconds
});
```

Where `2` is the number of seconds you want to delay, and everything else is built-in C or Objective-C constants/functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now, some days later I learned the very basics for iOS and Mac OS programing. Now I know what you mean. *thumbs up* for your great helpful answer.